# Javascript - Check if Object-Content has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, hash

**my solution**

```
// calculate Hash from Object
var jsString = $.toJSON(jsObject); 
var jsString = jsString.length;
var jsStringHashNew = $.md5(jsString);

// my Check
if(jsStringHashOld != jsStringHashNew)
{
   alert('new content in Object');
}
```

But this i maybe a little bit dirty? Right?

Does anybody know a a better(faster) solution?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: It is not reliable. What if a value is changed but has the same length? Another problem is that properties are not ordered. You *might* end up with two different hashes for the same object (though this is probably less likely). Do you only care about changes of values or could it also be that properties are added/removed from the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Underscore.js's [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js). (search source for `isEqual`)